How can I cancel the gas fee for all transactions in substrate?
I want to cancel the transaction fee occurring in substrate so that the transfer fee is 0 units.
Frontier Parachain Collator Template 1.0.0
Thanks
in the file lib.rs I reset the weights, but nothing has changed.
The raw-parachain-chanspec file is used at startup.json, but it does not contain information about the commission, perhaps it should be added? and how to do it?
